# Retrieve and modify a previously assigned event function?

Tags: javascript

Can I retrieve and modify a previously assigned event function?

For example I originally add an onclick event handler to a node, like this :

```
var someNode = document.getElementByID('someNode');

someNode.onclick = function(){
     //some stuff
};
```

Ideally later I would need to get back this event and modify the "some stuff" code content.

Is it doable in javascript?

Comment: If you want to get back that handler, that means a condition is implicit.  So, why not just put that condition inside of that handler?

Comment: thats an xy problem. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to modify an (onclick) event, but I have no idea if it is possible or not.

Comment: @Ele : Because when I originally add the event, I have no clue if the condition is met or not.

Comment: So you want to remove the first one and add another one?

Comment: @Nihoul why not just test for the condition inside the handler?

Comment: Hmm. It looks most of you think I'm not doing the right way... Let me some time to investigate your various help.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `onclick` event. Simply assign that to a new function will do. However, similar to most dynamic languages, function is not a data structure that you can easily modify. So keeping the same function but modifying it is AFAIK impossible.

The way I would suggest is to create a new function for your use, and assign it to the `onclick` property. However, JS is a very nice language that provide *closure* to your variables. So you can make a function that return a function to fit your need if you need some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish. But do you mean something like that ?

```
var someNode = document.getElementByID('someNode');

let customizablePart = function (e) {
   // do some stuff
}

someNode.onclick = function (e) {
     // unchangeable instructions
     customizablePart.call(this, e)
}

// later ...

customizablePart = function (e) {
  // do new stuff
}
```